# MySQL 5.6 - InnoDB - DATA_FREE is not utilized but table keeps growing

Tags: mysql, innodb

The `innondb_file_per_table = 1`.

We have a large table where the data_free is large.

We keep clearing older data from this table at regular interval.

Earlier (When were were on `MySQL 5.5`) we were observing data_free was getting consumed and with archival process it was increasing and later was consumed till next run of archival.

But after moving to `5.6`, we are seeing that the data_free is not utilized but the table keeps growing.

Any pointer why this should happen?

Answer (score 0):

That's life.  MySQL is not great at returning disk space to the OS.

Since it a separate .ibd file, you could do `OPTIMIZE TABLE` right after your periodic archive.  But then it will grow back to the large size.

Is the data a "sliding time"?  That is, do you keep a month's worth, then remove a day's worth each night?  This is one case where `PARTITIONs` shine.  `DROP PARTITION` *does* return the space used by the partition to the OS.  If you want to copy the old day to some other place, then you need "transportable tablespaces", and you will need 5.6 (or, better, 5.7).

More on how to use partitioning for such:  [*here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/) .